# How to group multiple aggregate results in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns an ID, item of highest value and maximum level that a user is on.

My query is as follows :

```
SELECT id,
MAX(item)   AS highest_item,
MAX(level)  AS highest_level
FROM data
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

How can I query the database so that I receive a total count of unique users, who are on the same highest level and have the same highest value item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the count(distcint id) grouped by the values you need. Eg. for both the values:

```
select count(distinct id ), highest_item, highest_level

    from ( 
    SELECT id,
    MAX(item)   AS highest_item,
    MAX(level)  AS highest_item
    FROM data
    GROUP BY 1
 ) t 
 group by highest_item, highest_level
 order by count(distinct id ) desc
```

or for highest_item

```
 select count(distinct id ), highest_item

    from ( 
    SELECT id
    MAX(item)   AS highest_item,
    MAX(level)  AS highest_level
    FROM data
    GROUP BY 1
 ) t 
 group by highest_item
order by count(distinct id ) desc
```

of for highest_level

```
 select count(distinct id ), highest_level

    from ( 
    SELECT id,
    MAX(item)   AS highest_item,
    MAX(level)  AS highest_level
    FROM data
    GROUP BY 1
 ) t 
 group by highest_level
 order by count(distinct id ) desc
```

Comment: Using your first suggestion to group by both I get a resulting table of simply count, which is not what i needed, I needed a table with the level #, the item ID, and a count of how many distinct users are on the same level with the same item. Could you also explain the purpose of the "t" character in your queries?

Comment: the levels are added  ..  the t is the table name for the subselect   from (     ) t ..  .. but how are related  the users  to the question  .( i have assumed  you meadn the countof the id)  . i don't see  any users  column in your query  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
Select id,count(Id) from data group by level,item having level=max(level) and item=max(item)
```